# Cloning most of a SQL entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

So I have a table with around 15 columns. Let's say that they're named 01, 02, 03 etc until 15. Let's say for example in the 4th column that it contains string entries that could be carat delimited. So for example an entry in the 4th column could be 'a^b^c^d'. I'd like to clone the entire row containing an entry with a carat delimited string except for the 4th column. I'd like my example from before to turn into a row each containing all the same information except for the 4th column which would just contain an a. Then another column that has all the same information except just a b in the 4th column, etc. If anyone could give me a little help to get started that'd be really helpful, thanks!

Comment: Let me rephrase it for you. You want to split one row to multiple where they differ 4 columns getting single distinct value, right?

Comment: Yes I want to split one row into multiple rows based on this 4th column containing a carat delimited string.

Comment: Which RDBMS you use?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

**[DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/369240)**

```
CREATE TABLE #table_name([01] NVARCHAR(100),
                         [02] NVARCHAR(100),
                         [03] NVARCHAR(100),
                         [04] NVARCHAR(100),
                         [05] NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #table_name
SELECT '1', '1', '1', 'a^b^c^d', '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2', '2', '2', 'e^f', '2';


;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT 
      [01], [02], [03], [05], 
      CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE([04],'^','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
   FROM #table_name
)
SELECT 
    [01]
   ,[02]
   ,[03]
   ,[04] = m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)')
   ,[05]
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n);
```

To change values in existing table you can use:

**[Demo2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/369243)**

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT 
      [01], [02], [03], [05], 
      CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE([04],'^','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
   FROM #table_name
)
SELECT 
    [01]
   ,[02]
   ,[03]
   ,[04] = m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)')
   ,[05]
INTO #auxilary_table
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)

TRUNCATE TABLE #table_name;

INSERT INTO #table_name
SELECT *
FROM #auxilary_table;

SELECT *
FROM #table_name;
```

Comment: I'm getting an invalid object name error on x.nodes. I'm also getting a cannot find either column  name m or aggregate m.n.value or ambiguous name m.n.